# Installing a Nest Thermostat

Tags: hvac, thermostat

Installing on a boiler system: in-floor heat. No fan, air, or humidifier. I only have 3 wires.  Red, blue, white. I was told I needed a common wire. My Honeywell programable thermostat (with batteries) only uses the red and white but there is a blue available.  I also have three older round thermostats with all three wires  attached.  I want to replace one of those with the Nest. Is blue a common wire?

Comment: Draw your existing circuit. Then consider how the new one fits in.

Comment: Keep in mind that the colors are not a reliable indicator of the function of a wire.  What is important is the label on the terminals in the HVAC unit as well as the thermostat.  Don't rely on the colors!  The "C" wire, if it exists, will be on a terminal labelled "C".

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to find out, is to connect the blue to the C on Nest.

And connect the red to the R (24 volt)

If it works then it was the common.

Nest will tell you if you have done it right, or not.

The white would go in W (for heating)

Comment: Thank you, I was worried that I could cause damage if I attached the blue wire to common.  Relief to know I will get a warning rather than ruin an expensive  unit.